# Flutter - How to map List of array to Widget

Tags: arrays, mongodb, list

I want to pass the array data from MongoDB to lists of widgets. However, I am getting an error of "type 'MappedListIterable<ApplicantsList, Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'List'". Can someone help me?

Here are my variables:

```
List<ApplicantsList> applicants;
var store, store1;
```

The applicants class / constructor:

```
class ApplicantsList {
  String name;
  String contact;

  ApplicantsList({this.name, this.contact});
}
```

Getting data from mongodb. (Works fine. I can get the data.)

```
Future <void> getApplicantInfo() async {

  AuthService().getRequestorApplicants().then((val) async {
    store = val.data[0];
    store1 = val.data[1];

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      applicants =[ ApplicantsList(name: store['parentname'], contact: 
      store['location']) ];
    }
  }); 

}
```

This is where I think I get the error. When passing the data to a _PendingCardDonor widget.

```
Container(
   child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
   stream: null,
   builder: (context, snapshot) {
   return Container(
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
   child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: <Widget>[
          Column(
              children: applicants.map((e) => _PendingCardDonor(e.name, e.contact,"Balubad, Mindoro"),),,
           ],
        ));
      }
    ),
  ),
```

The _PendingCardDonor widget

```
 Widget _PendingCardDonor (String name, String age, String location) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {

      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: getColorFromHex('#a19c9c'),
              offset: Offset(-1, 2),
              blurRadius: 4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: getColorFromHex('#faf7f7'),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.black,),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: AutoSizeText(name,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16,),
                              minFontSize: 13,
                              stepGranularity: 1,
                              maxLines:2),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: getColorFromHex('#faf7f7'),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.calendar_today_rounded, color: Colors.black, ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Text(age + " yrs old",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: getColorFromHex('#faf7f7'),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.location_pin, color: Colors.black,),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: AutoSizeText(location,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, ),
                              minFontSize: 13,
                              stepGranularity: 1,
                              maxLines:3),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: RaisedButton(
                elevation: 0.0,
                color: getColorFromHex('#FE9C8F'),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight, child: ViewPendingApplicant(
                    upass: widget.upass,
                    email: widget.email,
                    name: name,
                    age: age,
                    location: location,
                  )));
                },
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.folder_open,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "OPEN",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),

              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can add `.toList()` after `applicants.map` like this:

```
Container(
  child: StreamBuilder<Object>(
    stream: null,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              children: applicants
                .map((e) => _PendingCardDonor(e.name, e.contact,"Balubad, Mindoro")),
                .toList() // <-- HERE
            ),
          ]
        )
      );  
    }
  ),
),
```

Comment: Ohh I might have deleted it. Thanks for that! But I am still encountering error. It says the "The method 'map' was called on null. Tried calling: map<Widget>(Closure: (ApplicantsList) => Widget)' - I think it's because of getting data from db takes time. So it gets null at first but I don't know how I will implement it.

Comment: You can solve this simply by using ‘?.’ operator. Like ‘applicants?.map(...)’. Then if applicants is null, it will returns null instead of report the error of calling map on null. After that, you can use ‘??’ operator. It will return the value at its right side when the left side value is null, otherwise return left side value. So your final code will be ‘applicants?.map(...) ?? [Text(“fetching from longish”)]’

Comment: You can also adjust the UI hierarchy to move the Widget  that indicates loading status to the more suitable place. For example, when the applicants is null, return Text(“Fetching from mongodb”), otherwise return the applicants list.